# Troubleshooting Python Package Installation for Global Access and Modifiability on Windows 11 and Ubuntu

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

I have a problem with the installation of my own package so that it is accessible everywhere on the computer. I also want to make it modifiable at any time. So, I did the following (I specify that I am using Windows 11, but I have the same problem on my Ubuntu, so if you have a solution for that too, please do not hesitate):

- Created a `setup.py` file and placed it in the folder, giving the folder the name of the package.
- Navigated to the folder in question with the command `cd "/path/to/your/package"`.
- Executed the command `pip install -e .`. Everything apparently went well in the console, but afterward, when I try to use my package, nothing works. Python tells me that it cannot find the package in question. I also tried another approach by doing...

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/package")
```

but either it does not work well and it does not find the packages and python file inside the folder and in addition
vscode does not handle it well and the functions/class etc... are not colored and not clickable which is not practical,
do you know this problem and do you have a solution to offer me? thank you!
Here is my `setup.py` file if it can help (the goal is to make the package accessible throughout the computer, not to distribute it):

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="module",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

```
cd "/path/to/your/package"
pip install -e .
```

Comment: "_Python tells me that it cannot find the package in question._" What command did you run?